# Animate div when hovering over another div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My issue here is that I have a grid of images and titles for these images which all have the same class.

So the HTML for each image and title in the grid is

```
<a href="">
<div class="front-menu-image">
<img src="" width="224" height="224"/>
</div>
<div class="front-menu-title">TITLE</div>
</a>
```

I have tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    jQuery('.front-menu-image').hover(
        function () {
            jQuery(.front-menu-title).animate({height:'50'});
         },
        function () {
            jQuery(.front-menu-title).animate({height:'25'});
        }
    );  
});
```

But obviously this caused all in the grid to be animated, when I just want the one in question to be affected.

Comment: You can replace `jQuery` with the short selector: `$` . Also, your classes need to be between qoutes.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".front-menu-image").hover(
    function(){
      $(this).siblings(".front-menu-title").animate({height: '50'})
    }
  );
});
```

You can use **this** inside an event handler to refer to the current object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('.front-menu-image').hover(
        function () {
            jQuery(this).next('.front-menu-title').animate({height:'50'});
         },
        function () {
            jQuery(this).next('.front-menu-title').animate({height:'25'});
        }
    );  
});
```

It assigns the event handler the same, but inside it it looks for the next element with the title class, relative to what you're hovering over (see the use of `this`).

Answer (score 0):

This will animate only that image on which you will hover :-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

jQuery('.front-menu-image').on('hover', function () {
        jQuery(.front-menu-title).animate({height:'50'});
     },
    function () {
        jQuery(.front-menu-title).animate({height:'25'});
    }
);  
});
```

For knowing more about the difference between .click() and .on('click') , refere here [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)